# Loop will not print

Tags: java

I am writing a program that will calculate the amount of wages for 3,4,5,6,and 7 employees after 10-40 hours. I have written my code usuing a for loop and think I did it correctly. However the loop will not print. The only thing that shows up after I run the program is the system.out.print that is written before the loops.  here is my program.

```
public class Prog166d {
    // declares hourly wage as a constant 
    public static final int hourlyRate = 8;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(" Wages for 3 employees\n\n");

        //loop that increments employees.
        for (int employees = 3; employees >= 7; employees++) {
            System.out.println(" Wages for " + employees + " employees\n\n");

            //loop to calculate wage 
            for (int hours = 10; hours <= 40; hours += 10) {
                int wages = hourlyRate * hours;

                //output
                System.out.println("For" + hours + " hours worked, the wages are " + wages + "dollars");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Typo `employees>=7` should be `employees<=7`. Otherwise for `employees=3` condition `3>=7` is immediately false preventing loop from iterating even once.

Comment: loop will iterate as long as ur condition is `true` not the other way around..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is `for (int employees= 3; employees>=7; employees++)`
this way it will never go inside the loop coz `3<7`

`employees>=7` needs to be replaced with `employees<=7`

Comment: Oh I see. Silly mistake. Thank you !

Comment: Please don't post answers only pointing out a typographical issue or a missing character. Such answers are unlikely to help future visitors since they are specific to OP's code. Instead, flag or vote to close the question as off-topic as per the [help/on-topic].